# focus on a textbox using jquery without triggering onblur

Tags: jquery

I have textbox like below for password,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNewPass" value="" autocomplete="off" tabindex=2>
```

and I use the following code to check some conditions on the entered password, if any one condition is false then it shows an alert message and then focus on the textbox to enter again.

```
$("#txtNewPass").on('blur',function() {
    var newPass = $("#txtNewPass").val();

    var minNumberOfDigits = 6;
    var maxNumberOfDigits = 14;
    var message1 = "Password must be a combination of alphabets, numbers and more than 5 chars.";
    var condition = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$/;

    alert(newPass);
    if (newPass != "") {
        if (!condition.test(newPass) || (newPass.length < minNumberOfDigits || newPass.length > maxNumberOfDigits)) {
            $("#txtNewPass").focus();
            alert(message1);
            return;
        }
    }
})
```

But when focusing on the textbox it fires the onblur again, and the same error gets shown again and again, not stopping

How to fix this issue?

Comment: please check whether value exists or not in var newPass = $("#txtNewPass").val(), if exists continue with logic ,if not focus it.

Comment: Please pass `$("#txtNewPass").focus();` this your all else selection or prepared one function to pass the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make the checking only when the textfield is not empty else always focus on that input field
Note: This will work only if that field is mandatory.

Also please try console.log instead of alert, It seems to be working fine, can you try the below code and give your suggestions please

```
<script>    
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#txtNewPass").on('blur',function() {
        var newPass = $("#txtNewPass").val();

        if(newPass != ''){
            var minNumberOfDigits = 6;
            var maxNumberOfDigits = 14;
            var message1 = "Password must be a combination of alphabets, numbers and more than 5 chars.";
            var condition = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$/;

            console.log(newPass);
            if (newPass != "") {
                if (!condition.test(newPass) || (newPass.length < minNumberOfDigits || newPass.length > maxNumberOfDigits)) {
                    //$("#txtNewPass").val("");
                    $("#txtNewPass").focus();
                    console.log(message1);
                    return;
                }
            }

        }else{
            $("#txtNewPass").focus();   
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: it works, but i dont want to clear the password once error ocuur

Comment: @JM I have modified the code now, Just comment out this `$("#txtNewPass").val("");`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
var error = false;
$("#txtNewPass").keyup(()=>{error = true;});
$("#txtNewPass").on('blur',function() {if(!error) {$(this).focusout();return;}
var newPass = $("#txtNewPass").val();

var minNumberOfDigits = 6;
var maxNumberOfDigits = 14;
var message1 = "Password must be a combination of alphabets, numbers and more than 5 chars.";
var condition = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$/;

alert(newPass);
if (newPass != "") {
    if (!condition.test(newPass) || (newPass.length < minNumberOfDigits || newPass.length > maxNumberOfDigits)) {
       // setTimeout(()=>{$("#txtNewPass").click()},100);
        $("#txtNewPass").focus();
        alert(message1);error = false;
        return;
    }
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNewPass" value="" autocomplete="off" tabindex=2>
```